# What does `@@` mean in a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql

What does the "at symbol" mean in a PostgreSQL query?

For instance, I'm looking at a query where a WHERE condition is:

```
WHERE (to_tsvector('german', nodes.name) @@ plainto_tsquery('german', 'münd'))
```

I understand that this has something to do with ignoring the umlaut, but searching the web for `@@` part of it hasn't turned up an explanation so far.

A link to the right place in the docs would be an ideal answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## "Matches"

Ah, it just means "matches" in the context of a full-text search.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-MATCHING

Comment: See also all the [Text Search Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-textsearch.html).

Comment: Sounds like you found your own answer, but it wasn't marked as such.